# Python failure to PUT using urllib2

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I'm trying to do an http put using urllib2.

The server admin said I need to provide the data in the following format:
{"type":"store","data":["9953"]}

My code is as follows:

```
url = 'https://url.com/polling/v1/5cb401c5-bded-40f8-84bb-6566cdeb3dbb/stores'
request = urllib2.Request(url, data='{\"type\":\"store\",\"data\":[\"9953\"]}')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % creds)
request.add_header("Content-type", "application/json")
request.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
print "Data: %s" % request.get_data()
print "Accept: %s" % request.get_header("Accept")
print "Content-Type: %s" % request.get_header("Content-type")
print "Authorization: %s" % request.get_header("Authorization")
try:
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request, data )
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print e.read()
    exit()
data = json.loads(result.read())
print data
```

My output when I run this is:

```
Data: {"type":"store","data":["9953"]}
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic U1lTQ1RMOmFiYzEyMw==
```

Which is exactly what I was told to send

But I'm getting the following error:

```
BWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl$InputStreamWrapper@695dd38d; line: 2, column: 15])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you escaping double quotes (") inside of single quotes (')? (L2)

Comment: The app admin told me to "make sure you are properly escaping your double quotes".  Removing the escapes yields the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Notice these 2 lines of code:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data='{\"type\":\"store\",\"data\":[\"9953\"]}')

result = urllib2.urlopen(request, data)
```

In the first line, you are initializing the request by passing the `data` named parameter set to the JSON payload.  This appears to be correct.

However, then the second line passes in `data`, overwriting the payload that you initialized in the first line.  I assume that `data` here is some variable in the larger context of your program (not shown in the original question), and that this `data` variable is set to some different value, perhaps an invalid JSON payload.

If the payload in the first line is initialized correctly, then I suggest changing the second line to this:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```